# How to receive AJAX response as blob instead of string?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, file, flask

I have the following AJAX call, which I am using to get an Excel file from the backend (which is running Flask):

```
handleExport = (exportType) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("exportType", exportType);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/export',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
    }).done((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, data.name);
    })
}
```

The AJAX call goes through, but the `data` object in the `done` method is a string, instead of a blob, which is what I would expect. The flask route corresponding to the AJAX call is below:

```
@app.route("/export", methods = ['POST'])
def export():
    userid = session['userid']
    export_type = request.form['exportType']
    export = get_export(db, userid, export_type)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    export.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
    output.seek(0)
    return send_file(output, attachment_filename = "Promotions_Export.xlsx", mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel', as_attachment = True)
```